# Wordpressでajaxで外部のサービスのAPIにPOSTしたいとき

Tags: api, wordpress, ajax

```
$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url: URL,      // POST送信先のURL
  crossDomain: true,
  contentType:'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  data: date,
  success: function(json_data) {
      if (!json_data[0]) {
          alert('Transaction error. ' + json_data[1]);
          return;
      }
      console.log(json_data);
  },
  error: function() {
      alert('Server Error. Pleasy try again later.');
  },
  complete: function() {
      button.attr('disabled', false);
  }
});
});
```

上記のような感じでWordpressで外部サービスにPOSTしたいのですが、

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load "送信先のURL". No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '送信元URL' is therefore not allowed access.
```

上記のようなエラーを吐いてしまいます。

以下のような記事を参考にしましたがうまくいかず、wordpressの仕様でうまくいっていないのでしょうか？
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433655/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPressは多分関係ないと思うので、WordPressを使わないページで同様のコードを書いて試してみていただきたいですが...。

ブラウザでは Same-origin Policy というルールに基づき、異なるドメイン間での通信に制限があります。具体的には、CORSというルールに従ってサーバー側が「そのドメインからは呼び出してもいい」ということをレスポンスヘッダを使ってブラウザに伝えなければいけません。

そして `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` はそのようなヘッダがないことを示しています。ですからまず考えられるのは、**そのAPIが異なるドメインからの呼び出しに対応していない**、という可能性です。この照会は実際のPOSTの前に行われるので、APIキーの渡し方以前の問題です。

このあたりは呼び出したいAPIを具体的に提示していただかないとこちらでは調べようがないので、ここでは書けないのでしたらご自身でその外部サービスのヘルプを読んだり、問い合わせていただくことになります。

もし対応していなければ、ブラウザから直接ではなく、呼び出し元ページのあるサーバーからPHPなどのプログラムで呼び出しを行う必要があるかと思います。

ちなみに `$.ajax()` の crossDomain オプションは、異なるドメインへの通信では自動的に true になるので、通常明示する必要はありません。

Answer (score 0):

本件「クロスドメイン」と言われる動作になっており、
javascriptが置いてあるサーバー(質問者様のサーバー)の問題ではなく
ajaxでアクセスしようとしているサーバー(外部サービスのサーバー)の問題となります。

ご記載いただいているエラーにも記載されていますが。
レスポンスヘッダーにAccess-Control-Allow-Originが必要だが、ない。
と言われております。

Publicでサービスを公開しているのではない場合、APIキーの認証だったりドメインの登録、署名の登録が必要だったりします。
「外部サービス」側でAPIキーに認証が必要だったり、ドメイン指定が必要だったり、のようなユーザー設定項目が存在しませんでしょうか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。APIキーの 「アクセスキー」、「シークレットキー」はdateの変数の中に含まれています。headerなどに含めないといけないのでしょうか？

Comment: 「外部サービス」側の仕様によりますので何とも言えませんが、APIキーが指定されていても、それを悪用されないように「特定リファラー(サイト)からの使用」、「特定PC(IP)からの使用」、「署名がついているか」・・・etcなどの認証がかかっている場合があります。「外部サービス」ごとに違いますので、当方からは詳細な設定方法はわかりかねますが、その辺りの制限や設定方法が「外部サービス」の使用方法等に明記されているはずなのでそちらを確認いただいた方が良いと思います。